# How to display content of a file which added from past 5 mins without scanning whole file in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have DB error log file, it will grow continuously.
Now i want to set some error monitoring on that file for every 5 minutes.
The problem is i don’t want to scan whole file for every 5 minutes(when monitoring cron executed), because it may grow very big in future. Scanning through whole(big) file for every 5 mins will consume bit more resources.
So i just want to scan only the lines which were inserted/written to the log during last 5 mins interval. 
Each error recorded in log will have Timestamp prepend to it like below:

180418 23:45:00 [ERROR] mysql got signal 11.

So i want to search with pattern [ERROR] only on lines which were added from last 5 mins(not whole file) and place the output to another file.

Please help me here.
Feel free if u need more clarification on my question.

I’m using RHEL 7 and i’m trying to implement above monitoring through bash shell script

Comment: If the only changes are appends, you can just seek() to the old size and read from there. See `man 2 seek` for the C call; pretty much every programming language (you aren't telling us which one you're using) has access to it. To determine what position you stopped reading at and serialize that location, you can use the `tell()` call.

Comment: ...if you can't serialize a byte offset (which you should!), the alternative is to bisect the file to find your starting timestamp quickly. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247508/binary-search-in-a-sorted-text-file, and the `bsearch` tool by @ole-tange mentioned therein.

Comment: (btw, I *hope* that your date format is `YYMMDD HH:MM:SS`; if it's `DDMMYY`, your job got much harder).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, it’s YYMMDD format, and i want to implement this monitoring through shell script.

Comment: You should specify that in the question. Tag it `shell`, or a more specific shell such as `bash` if you're comfortably using a `#!/bin/bash` shebang.

Comment: Please also specify your OS, at least enough to know if we can use GNU coreutils/GNU find/&c. extensions.

Comment: Since your program might not run exactly every 5 minutes and you probably do not want to miss seeing any line, do you want "last 5 minutes' worth of the file based on timestamps" or "everything added to the file since the last time I checked"?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, *nod* -- that's why I'm providing both. I suppose one could combine the modes -- bisect for a timestamp if no byte offset exists, use a byte offset otherwise.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh! My browser did not display your answer until after I refreshed the page, so my question for the OP is moot now I guess.

Comment: BTW, in a real-world situation, I wouldn't be using a cron-style job for this purpose at all; instead, I'd be using something like [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) to stream events directly into a message queue for [CEP-style analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_event_processing) in real time. See [Riemann](http://riemann.io/) for an example of a built-to-purpose tool.

Answer (score 2):

#### Serializing the Byte Offset

This picks up where the last instance left off. If you run it every 5 minutes, then, it'll scan 5 minutes of data.

Note that this implementation knowingly can scan data added during an invocation's run twice. This is a little sloppy, but it's much safer to scan overlapping data twice than to never read it at all, which is a risk that can be run if relying on `cron` to run your program on schedule (likewise, `sleep`s can run over the requested time if the system is busy).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=$1; shift                    # first input: filename
grep_opts=( "$@" )                # remaining inputs: grep options

dir=$(dirname -- "$file")         # extract directory name to use for offset storage
basename=${file##*/}              # pick up file name w/o directory
size_file="$dir/.$basename.size"  # generate filename to use to store offset

if [[ -s $size_file ]]; then      # ...if we already have a file with an offset...
  old_size=$(<"$size_file")       # ...read it from that file
else
  old_size=0                      # ...otherwise start at the front.
fi

new_size=$(stat --format=%s -- "$file") || exit  # Figure out current size

if (( new_size < old_size )); then
  old_size=0                          # file was truncated, so we can't trust old_size
elif (( new_size == old_size )); then
  exit 0                              # no new contents, so no point in trying to search
fi

# read starting at old_size and grep only that content
dd iflag=skip_bytes skip="$old_size" if="$file" | grep "${grep_opts[@]}"; grep_retval=$?

# if the read failed, don't store an updated offset
(( ${PIPESTATUS[0]} != 0 )) && exit 1

# create a new tempfile to store offset in
tempfile=$(mktemp -- "${size_file}.XXXXXX") || exit

# write to that temporary file...
printf '%s\n' "$new_size" > "$tempfile" || { rm -f "$tempfile"; exit 1; }

# ...and if that write succeeded, overwrite the last place where we serialized output.
mv -- "$tempfile" "$new_size" || exit

exit "$grep_retval"
```

---

#### Alternate Mode: Bisect For The Timestamp

Note that this can miss content if you're relying on, say, `cron` to invoke your code every 5 minutes on-the-dot; storing byte offsets can thus be more accurate.

Using the [`bsearch` tool by Ole Tange](https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/blob/master/bsearch/bsearch):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=$1; shift

start_date=$(date -d 'now - 5 minutes' '+%y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
byte_offset=$(bsearch --byte-offset "$file" "$start_date")

dd iflag=skip_bytes skip="$byte_offset" if="$file" | grep "$@"
```

Comment: is PIPESTATUS reliable? I recall comments saying it wasn't.

Comment: It's a bashism, so it's not reliably available on non-bash shells. That's the only manner of "unreliable" I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be something like this:

```
DB_FILE="FULL_PATH_TO_YOUR_DB_FILE"

current_db_size=$(du -b "$DB_FILE" | cut -f 1)
if [[ ! -a SOME_PATH_OF_YOUR_CHOICE/last_size_db_file ]] ; then
    tail --bytes $current_db_size $DB_FILE > SOME_PATH_OF_YOUR_CHOICE/log-file_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)
else
    if [[ $(cat last_size_db_file) -gt $current_db_size ]] ; then
        previously_readed_bytes=0
    else
        previously_readed_bytes=$(cat last_size_db_file)
    fi
    new_bytes=$(($current_db_size - $previously_readed_bytes))
    tail --bytes $new_bytes $DB_FILE > SOME_PATH_OF_YOUR_CHOICE/log-file_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)
fi
printf $current_db_size > SOME_PATH_OF_YOUR_CHOICE/last_size_db_file
```

this prints all bytes of `DB_FILE` not previously printed to `SOME_PATH_OF_YOUR_CHOICE/log-file_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)`

Note that `$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)` will be the current 'full' date at the time of creating the log file

you can make this an script, and use `cron` to execute that script every five minutes; something like this:

```
*/5 * * * * PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT
```

Comment: `$(cat foo)` is significantly slower than `$(<foo)`, a bashism which doesn't need to fork a subprocess or invoke an external binary. And you're missing a whole bunch of quotes -- run the code in your answer through http://shellcheck.net/.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

First, read the whole log once so far. 
If you reach the end, collect and read new lines for a timespan (in my example 9 seconds, for faster testing, while my dummy server appends to the logfile every 3 seconds).

After the timespan, echo the cache, clear the cache (an array `arr`), loop and sleep for some time, so that this process doesn't consume all CPU time.

First, my dummy logfile writer:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# dummy logfile writer
#
while true
do
  s=$(( $(date +%s) % 3600))
  echo $s server msg
  sleep 3
done >> seconds.log
```

Startet via `./seconds-out.sh &`.

Now the more complicated part:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# consume a logfile as written so far. Then, collect every new line
# and show it in an interval of $interval
#
interval=9 # 9 seconds
#
printf -v secnow '%(%s)T' -1 
start=$(( secnow % (3600*24*365) ))
declare -a arr
init=false
while true
do
  read line
  printf -v secnow '%(%s)T' -1 
  now=$(( secnow % (3600*24*365) ))

  # consume every line created in the past
  if (( ! init ))
  then
    # assume reading a line might not take longer than a second (rounded to whole seconds)
    while (( ${#line} > 0 && (now - start) < 2 ))
    do
      read line
      start=$now
      echo -n "." # for debugging purpose, remove  
      printf -v secnow '%(%s)T' -1 
      now=$(( secnow % (3600*24*365) ))
    done
    init=1
    echo "init=$init" # for debugging purpose, remove 
  # collect new lines, display them every $interval seconds
  else
    if ((${#line} > 0 ))
    then
      echo -n "-" # for debugging purpose, remove 
      arr+=("read: $line \n")
    fi
    if (( (now - start) > interval ))
    then
      echo -e "${arr[@]]}"
      arr=()
      start=$now
    fi
  fi
  sleep .1
done < seconds.log
```

Output with logfile generator in 3 seconds, running for some time, then starting the read-seconds.sh script, with debugging output activated:

```
./read-seconds.sh 
.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................init=1
---read: 1688 server msg 
 read: 1691 server msg 
 read: 1694 server msg 

---read: 1697 server msg 
 read: 1700 server msg 
 read: 1703 server msg 

----read: 1706 server msg 
 read: 1709 server msg 
 read: 1712 server msg 
 read: 1715 server msg 

^C
```

- Every dot represents a logfile line from the past and therefor skipped.
- Every dash represents a logfile line collected.

Comment: `while (true)`, not `while true`? That's a lot of performance to pay for readability.

Comment: I'd also suggest `printf -v now_sec '%(%s)T' -1`, if targeting modern bash, to avoid the performance impact of invoking `date`. And, of course, `printf` instead of `echo -n` or `echo -e`.

Comment: The bigger concern -- as I follow this, you're doing a read loop to the last timestamp, not seeking there directly? Time needed to read is still going to scale linearly with total file size, which defeats the whole purpose of this question.

Comment: The question was `i don’t want to scan whole file for every 5 minutes`, so this scans the whole file only once. Then collects the data for every 5 minutes (for testing every 9 seconds). Thanks for the hint about printf -v ... T and `while true`.

Comment: Yes, but the point of not scanning the file is to not get slower as the file gets longer -- the OP is clear in the question that their purpose is limiting resource consumption. If you read the lines and throw them away, you're still reading them, so you pay the I/O cost -- which, for bash's `read`, is a particularly high price since it reads one byte at a time.